# Unable to debug C++ eclipse makefile project

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse

I imported an existing C++ project with working Makefiles. And in the
project property, I ticked off "Use default build" and "Generate
Makefile Automatically"

However I can not debug it. The error is No source available for
"main() " . I setup the Source  in the Run/Debug Dialog in all
possible ways I can imagine, and get the same error.

I am using Eclipse Cpp Juno Linux. Any solution please??

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding the `-g` flag to the build command in the makefile? Also refresh the project once you have transferred all the files.

Comment: Sorry i am new at Linux platform. Will you tell me how can i will do that?